# Page preview works fine while page rendering fails

Tags: 2011, publishing

My preview works fine through Tridion UI and also through template builder.

When I publish the page I get the following error.

```
JScriptException: Expression 'RenderComponentPresentation()' had error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

I have this statement in my TBB.

```
 Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.Binary b = engine.PublishingContext.RenderedItem.AddBinary(file, "image.png", strGroup, name, "image/png");
```

I also do not get any error logs in Tridion events. But I have a warning like this.This warning ocurs as well in other environment also but still publish is success.

```
AddBinary was called with relatedComponent=null resulting in unmanaged binaries in Content Delivery. Please specify a related Component to prevent issues with (un)deploying binaries.
```

The same page is also getting published in another Tridion environment.

Can you suggest any reason for this.

Comment: Could you post your dwt code for your page layout?  are you sure you're not running the preview for a different page, and when publishing another you are seeing this failure?

Comment: @johnwinter. Thank you for posting. I am sure that preview for the same page only.

Comment: they i think it's best you share some code for your dwt template :)

Comment: @johnwinter. I do not have dwt code but I have c# TBB in a dll.:(

Comment: @johnwinter. I have edited the question. Can you check it now.

Comment: Since it looks like it's a condition only happening when you're publishing, try attaching a debugger to tcmpublisher.exe and walk through your code... life saver!

Comment: Mihai made a [guide on *which* `AddBinary` to use in 2011](http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/03/which-addbinary-not-to-use.html). The example listed in this question seems to match one of the obsolete ones (5 params with the middle being an SG). Could the issue be the call itself?

Comment: The warning related to AddBinary is not the cause of the failure. Adding unmanaged binaries (without related Component) to publish package will result in orphan binaries in deployer. That is, when unpublished they will not be automatically removed. Your problem seems to be in the Component Template more specifically any of the TBBs in it. Please take a look at them, also check if you can get more detail on the error message like the stack trace which might help to isolate which TBB is causing the failure.

Answer (score 6):

There are (at least) three reasons why preview might succeed while publishing fails:

- Your (c#) template code may use the RenderInstruction.RenderMode property to take a different action for preview and publish
- Code which depends on assemblies in the GAC may fail if this assembly is only present on the CME server, not on the publisher server (this can only happen if you use a separate publisher machine)
- The template code may fail in publishing if you made a change to an assembly (for instance one in the GAC) on the server very recently and haven't restarted the publisher service.

I hope this gives you some idea of where to look for a solution.